# Android MPhil Charts: Adding Labels

Tags: android

Apparently, Mr. Jahoda's fantastic library once provided constructors for data with labels: e.g. `PieChart pieChart= new PieChart(names,data)`, where `names` is a list of strings. According to the documentation at https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.3/javadoc/, however, it no longer does so. So my question is, how do we supply names for each piece of a pie chart, or, for that matter, for any chart?

Answer (score 0):

To make pie chart please follow example below and I used v3.0.3 of library for this example:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(66, "Today"));
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(44, "Left"));

    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
    pieDataSet.setColors(Color.BLUE,Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pieDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);

    pieChart.getDescription().setText("");
    pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pieChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    pieChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
    pieChart.setCenterText("1600 Steps");
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(22);
    pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);

   pieChart.getLegend().setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.ABOVE_CHART_LEFT);
    pieChart.getLegend().setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
    pieChart.animateY(1000);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
}
```

}